# Does fstream open have trouble with larger files?

Tags: c++, unix, fstream

I'm trying to open `/usr/share/dict/words` with the following code:

```
fstream f;
f.open("/usr/share/dict/words");

// why is this returning false?
bool open = f.is_open();
```

I'm wondering why `f.is_open()` is returning false?

**More info**: when I try a smaller test file containing on the order of 20 lines `f.is_open()` returns true. Perhaps `f.open` is trying to load the entire file into memory?

Comment: I would guess it has nothing to do with the file size.  `fstream` _might_ have trouble with big files, but only when you try to seek about and compare offsets, which you aren't doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not work because you are opening the file for reading and writing. Unless you are running as root, you do not have permissions to write to this file.

If you open it just for reading it will work:

```
f.open("/usr/share/dict/words", fstream::in);
```

Answer (score 5):

The fstream.open() function is declared thusly:

```
 void open (const char *filename,
        ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out );
```

i.e. it opens the file for reading and writing. Your process probably does not have permissions to open that file for writing unless you're running as root. Open it for reading only with

```
  f.open("/usr/share/dict/words", ios_base::in);
```

Comment: ...or better yet change the stream type to `ifstream` since only input can be done on it